# Cloudwatch integration with xmatters

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, xmatters

I want to integrate cloudwatch with xmatters. I know I can use xmatters integration agent to integrate xmatters with other apps but how to access cloudwatch alarms. Is there any JAVA API which I can use to access cloudwatch alarms and then redirect it to xmatters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

(Shameless plug) I wrote an article on how to setup an integration to CloudWatch. Check it out [here](https://support.xmatters.com/hc/en-us/articles/214413623)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there have Java API for retrieve CloudWatch alarms and history. [API Ref.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html)

I guess you want the alert notify to XMatters when that happened. The CloudWatch alarms mechanism is base on SNS service. So, my redirect to **outside web service** approach step is:

1. Implement AWS Lambda function for send message to **outside web service**. Use node.js send REST post is pretty easy, or you can use Java too.
2. Create SNS Topic and add the Lambda subscription for it.
3. Create a CloudWatch alarm to above SNS Topic.

The message pass path is **CloudWatch alarm -> SNS -> Lambda -> outside service**.

Good Luck!